# FlashPlayer on OpenBSD?

Tags: openbsd, adobe-flash

What are my choices in 2011? Or it's better to download the flash videos? (but there aren't any solutions to download every type of videos, only youtube..).
Or are there any "linux-emulations" for OBSD?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [FAQ](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq13.html#flashplugin) (really):

> #### 13.14 - Can I have Flash support in my web browser? (i386 only)
>
> Firstly, if you are just looking to watch flash videos from common websites, there are a number of options in packages, including: get_flash_videos, minitube, youtube-dl, get_iplayer and yt.
>
> The Flash plugin is distributed by Adobe in binary form only. Adobe does not provide a native OpenBSD plugin, but there is a Linux plugin which you can use under Linux emulation. This plugin is available only for the i386 platform.
>
> Before continuing, it is a good idea to read about Linux emulation in the compat_linux(8) manual page, and also FAQ 9 - Running Linux binaries on OpenBSD.

Answer (score 2):

The open source [Gnash](http://www.gnu.org/s/gnash/) project states that [OpenBSD provides packages](http://wiki.gnashdev.org/OpenBSD). Use those. It's not a perfect AdobeFlash replacement but it's open source and so can be compiled on systems Adobe doesn't pre-compile for.

Answer (score 1):

FlashVideoReplacer works for most sites on OpenBSD, no problem.
Gnash plugin for the rest, like live streaming sites (Justin.tv/megavideo).

Or if you have a 64bit CPU install Debian, install VirtualBox, load OpenBSD and whenever you absolutely must look at a Flash video, switch to Debian to view it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [alternate solution for playing videos](http://blather.michaelwlucas.com/archives/865) in Firefox on OpenBSD.

Comment: Please at least summarize the solution in your answer, don't leave it with no content other than a link. Thanks for participating!

Comment: Also you should note specifically that this is a solution to mix together other substitute players for video and other media, not actually install flash.

Comment: while it is true that this is more of an alternative to flash rather than a solution, I can confirm the firefox add-on + gecko-mediaplayer solution as by far the best alternative to actually using flash.